# Is it possible to define function type in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I wrote the following code.

```
type NumAndStr = { num: number; str: string };

type A<T> = (item: T) => {
  key: keyof T;
  func: (value: T[keyof T]) => void;
};

const test: A<NumAndStr> = (item) => {
  return {
    key: "num",
    func: (value) => {}, // I expect 'value: number'
  };
};
```

However, since the type of 'value' is 'number | string', I fixed the code as follows

```
type NumAndStr = { num: number; str: string };

type B<T> = <K extends keyof T>(
  item: T,
) => {
  key: K;
  func: (value: T[K]) => void;
};

// error!
const test: B<NumAndStr> = (item) => {
  return {
    key: "num",
    func: (value) => {},
  };
};
```

How can I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be your help.
but you have to change some code
can you confirm the below code?

```
type B<T extends {}, K = keyof T> = (
  item: any,
) => {
  func: (value: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never) => void;
};

// correct
const test1: B<NumAndStr, 'num'> = (item) => {
  return {
    func: (value) => {
      // value is expected as a number
    },
  };
};
```